# Multifield in solr and document boosting based on terms

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Folks,

We want to arrange document based on terms repeating in the multifield.

Assume We have following multifield in the document.

```
Doc1 - item1 [1000,1000,2000,3000,5000] item2 [1000,2000,3000]
Doc2 - item1 [1000,1000,1000,3000,5000] item2 [1000,2000,3000]
```

When user queries with the term 1000 we want document (Doc2) to appear first as 1000 is repeating 4 times in the document. In document 1 it is coming 3 times.

Queries

1) How to achieve this ?

2) Any code sample to do it with solrj(JAVA libaray for solr) ?

Comment: All else being equal, this should already be the case.  That's the "tf" part of "tf-idf".

Comment: Can you elaborate more we are beginner in solr. Appriciate your help

Comment: http://kylewilliams.co.za/2015/03/28/getting-term-frequency-document-frequency-tf-idf-and-other-statistics-from-solr ( there is no function like tf we need to use termFreq ?)

Comment: I'm saying that scoring a document higher when the term being searched occurs more frequently, as you describe, is part of the default behavior in Lucene/Solr (or *any* tf-idf scoring algorithm, by definition).

Answer (score 0):

Like femtoRgon was saying, it's the default behavior of solr to score documents higher if they match the query more times than other documents. That being said, if this feature is not working, you could try query boosting:

```
q=1000^2
```

Boosting a query makes it more important than the other queries and each occurrence of 1000 will add to the score by twice the normal amount after ^2.

Using SolrJ, this would look like:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("1000^2");

QueryResponse resp = solr.query(query);
```